# intercept & coefficients interpretation values when using Scikit-learn regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-algebra

I have data that contains   a, b, c features, and R  result

```
a     b     c          R
245   49    158    166.6543133
3     195   191    100.3637372
.      .      .        .
```

I applied Linear regression using scikit learn [Linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) and got :

intercept `B0`  and `[k0,k1,k2]` Coefficients.

How can I predict the result using these variables without the need to use the `predict` function?

**Edit :**

I obtained the data by applying RGB to XYZ (CEI) and indeed the coefficients are similar to the standard formula.

```
Standard formula coeff    :  [0.4887180  0.3106803  0.2006017]
Linear regression coeff   :  [0.488718   0.3106803  0.2006017]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the variable yhat  as

```
yhat = B0 + k0 * x1 + k1 * x2 + k2 * x3
```

Where x1,x2 and x3 are your independent variables.

Note:

- The above is the equation for a linear regression model and can be extended to any number of variables.
- `yhat` stores the predicted value for a given value of x1,x2 and x3 based on the estimated coefficients

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by data scaled  using "StandardScaler" before fitting

Comment: Even if you have scaled the data, the `fit` function will give you an intercept. You have to set `intercept=False` in `LinearRegression()` to remove the intercept